# Google Colab can't use the GPU

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I'm kinda new to Google colab and have taken the Colab pro to train my neural nets but when computing the code I see that only the system RAM is used and the GPU Ram isn't used.

Is there any settings to force the code to be computed on the GPU?

Thanks for your help

I tried this to force the code to use the GPU but it still doesn't work:

for iteration in range(n_iterations):
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab's free version operates on a dynamic and undisclosed usage limit system, designed to manage access to computational resources like GPUs and TPUs. These limits, including runtime durations, availability of certain GPU types, and cooldown periods between sessions, can vary over time and are not transparently communicated to users. This approach helps prioritize resources for interactive use and moderate the consumption of long-running computations.

Frequent or heavy use can lead to shortened runtime durations, more frequent disconnections, and extended cooldown periods before reconnecting to a GPU, ranging from hours to days or even weeks. Google monitors the usage of individual accounts as well as related accounts, adjusting limits to prevent abuse of the system. Users facing restrictions receive generic messages about usage limits without specific reasons for disconnections or access denial, and there's no straightforward way for users to track their own usage. This opacity maintains Google's control over resource allocation and prevents users from circumventing the system's restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something similiar and found this explanation on Github
https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut/issues/2465

> I think the reason that Colab now uses 1% of the GPU is because Google
> made an update to CUDA 12.2 recently. Tensorflow-2.10.0 automatically
> installs on Colab, so it needs CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1 (according to
> the Linux GPU section here). A temporary solution is to connect to a
> GPU runtime -> click tools -> command palette -> type in and select
> 'use fallback runtime'. But this will only work until early Jan
> unfortunately.

The ulitmate solution that worked for those in the thread is  to run

> - !apt update && apt install cuda-11-8

before running other code in Colab.